# How do you reference a type in a statically imported (from html) file while using jsdoc+typechecking/linting?

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

Consider the following vanillaJS/HTML application:

```
- index.html
- main.js
```

Index.html looks like this:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
        body{
            margin: 0px;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="https://pixijs.download/release/pixi.js"></script> 
    <script src="main.js" type="module" defer></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    
  </body>
  </html>
```

main.js is as follows:

```js
//@ts-check
const app = new PIXI.Application({ 
    resizeTo:window,
    antialias: true,
    autoDensity: true,
    resolution: 2 });
  document.body.appendChild(app.view);

/**
 * 
 * @param {string} name 
 */
function sayHello(name){
    console.log(`hello ${name}`)
}
/**
```

the `PIXI` type def is not found because it is imported in the html. Since this is JS, this doesn't affect execution, but is annoying in my IDE because it flags this as an error.
Using vanilla JS, I cannot import PIXI without using a bundler which I would really prefer not to do. How do I declare that a type def for `PIXI` exists somewhere, but not here?